# Set boolean value without quotes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, boolean

I'm using xslt to parse XML and generate a json structure as the output.  I have one setting in my json output that needs to be a boolean, but have not been able to set this value and have the double quotes excluded.

Inside a choose -> When -> otherwise I want to set either true or false.

I'm getting as output:

```
                 "likeTheColor" : "true"
```

but I want :

```
                 "likeTheColor" : true
```

How can I set a json entry to boolean and not have the double quotes included.

Here is a snippet of the xsl I've created:

```
<xsl:choose>                                                        
  <xsl:when test="starts-with(snx:colorOK, 'none') = 'true'">
     "likeTheColor" : "<xsl:value-of select="translate(false(),'&#34;','')"/>",
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
     "likeTheColor" : "<xsl:value-of select="translate(true(),'&#34;','')"/>",
  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your XSLT and we can suggest how to modify it. (Also: your 'but I want' code has an odd number of double quote marks.)

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the missing ", and I added in a snippet of the xsl.  My last attempt was to use translate, but it has no impact on the "true".  Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your true/false value has quotes around it because you are putting quotes around it:

```
 Here --->"<xsl:value-of select="translate(false(),'&#34;','')"/>"<--- And here
```

Your approach is way more complicated than it needs to be. You can replace all nine lines of the code in your post with this one line:

```
"likeTheColor" : <xsl:value-of select="not(starts-with(snx:colorOK, 'none'))" />,
```

Comment: Yes, I'm new to xslt, and I appreciate your time and help.  Your suggestions worked perfectly.